# SVG glow filter showing wrong color

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I took pretty much exactly the [filter code from here](https://codepen.io/dipscom/pen/mVYjPw) (just playing with the flood color, radius and std. deviation to get the exact effect I wanted):

```
    <defs>
        <filter id="sofGlow" height="300%" width="300%" x="-75%" y="-75%">
        <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="4" in="SourceAlpha" result="thicken" />
        <feGaussianBlur in="thicken" stdDeviation="10" result="blurred" />
        <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,186,255)" result="glowColor" />
        <feComposite in="glowColor" in2="blurred" operator="in" result="softGlow_colored" />
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="softGlow_colored"/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs>
```

I applied it to one SVG I was working on, and it turned out as expected - a light blue ish glow.

I then tried applying it to another SVG, and it is turning out like a black glow.  I even tried changing the flood color to `rgb(255, 0, 0)` and it still looks black.

Why would it be doing that, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] you've not shown us what SVG you're applying it to to get the effect you describe

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Demo.
https://codepen.io/vccodepen/pen/qyjoNr

You can set two filters and give different ID name in same `<svg>`. In other `<svg>`, simply assigned the filter's ID you want.